# How to calculate a number representing the lowest possible weight difference

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Input data: A list of the weights.

Output data: A number representing the lowest possible weight difference.

for exmaple:

```
assert checkio([10, 10]) == 0, "1st example"
assert checkio([10]) == 10, "2nd example"
assert checkio([5, 8, 13, 27, 14]) == 3, "3rd example"
assert checkio([5, 5, 6, 5]) == 1, "4th example"
assert checkio([12, 30, 30, 32, 42, 49]) == 9, "5th example"
assert checkio([1, 1, 1, 3]) == 0, "6th example"
```

that is my code:

```
import random
def checkio(data):  
    for i in range(1,k):
        half_sum = (reduce（lambda x,y:x+y,data）)/2
        k = len(data)
    return min(lambda a:a >= half_sum,map(sum(random.sample(data,i))))
```

but the code doesn't work,please help me! many thanks!

Comment: A function shouldn't be the first argument to `min`.

Comment: Do you mean the lowest possible difference of two weights?

Comment: @LevLevitsky thanks! i'm trying to fix it..

Comment: @arshajii no ,maybe three weights or more.for example:checkio([5, 8, 13, 27, 14]) == 3, "3rd example"   the answer is 27+8-13-14-5 = 3

Comment: Ok, but not *all* of the weights have to be used?

Comment: @arshajii  Need to use any weight

Comment: @cedrichu, Maybe I don't understand the question properly, but if you can use any of weights, why couldn't you write `27 - 14 - 13 = 0` for third example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh... looks you're cheating on http://www.checkio.org/ :)

Anyway, here is the (working) solution is submited there:

```
def checkio(stones):
    def subcheckio(stones, left, rite):
        if len(stones) == 0:
            return abs(left - rite)

        scores = []
        nstones = stones[1:]
        scores.append(subcheckio(nstones, left + stones[0], rite))
        scores.append(subcheckio(nstones, left, rite + stones[0]))

        return min(scores)

    return subcheckio(stones, 0, 0)
```

Ok, because your question was about fixing your code, here's another version based on what you posted:

```
import itertools

def checkio(data):
    s = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,data) # s is the sum, you don't need a loop
    half_sum = s / 2

    # instead of random.sample, using itertools to find all possible combinations
    # of all possibles lenghts
    perms = []
    for i in range(len(data) + 1):
        p = itertools.combinations(data, i)
        perms += p

    # min of a list comprehension to find the minimal sum >= half_sum
    m = min([a for a in map(sum, perms) if a >= half_sum])
    # that's the sum of "what's left", members of the list no in the choosen sum
    n = s - m
    # we want the difference between the two
    return abs(n - m)
```

Comment: Aha I'm trying to fix my answer

Comment: :) ok,i will. your idea is better than mine